# No entiendo muy bien a que se refiere Android Studio con esto

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, onclicklistener

Tengo un Frame layout, y le he querido poner un OnTouchListener, me funciona correctamente pero no entiendo por que me sale este aviso.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Amigo acostumbra agregar texto, en ocasiones las imágenes no son muy visibles, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que debes sobreescribir el metodo performClick() porque no intentas meter tu switch en este

```
@Override
public boolean performClick(View view, MotionEvent event){
    switch(){...}
    return true;
}
```

o utilizar onTouch()

```
@override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(){...}
    return true;
}
```